# Using a function defined in a DLL from C++ code

Tags: c++, qt, dll, g++, mingw32

I built Qt from source (dlls) and am trying to build an application that uses the Qt dlls. I don't have a lot of experience with C++ so I'm running into what I'm sure is a very basic issue.

My builds are failing on the includes with errors like so:

```
Fatal error: QNetworkProxy: No such file or directory
```

Here is the g++ command I am using (I also used -L to add the correct folder to the lib path, but that also didn't work):

```
g++ -l..\..\wkqt\bin\QtCore4.dll -l..\..\wkqt\bin\QtNetwork4.dll -l..\..\wkqt\bin\QtWebKit4.dll -I..\include -Ishared -Ipdf -Ilib -Iimage -o ..\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe pdf\*.cc lib\*.cc image\*.cc shared\*.cc
```

I tried in Visual Studio as well (assuming it wouldn't build, but I wanted to see if I could at least include the Qt dlls from there properly) and I am getting the same errors. Am I doing something wrong with the way I am compiling with g++? If I am linking with the Dlls properly then what is the proper way to use Qt functions from my code?

To clarify, I am not looking for how to properly use Qt. My question is: what is the proper way to use functions defined in any Dll from native C++ code? I apologize if this is a very basic question, but I'm unable to find a clear answer on Google and I don't have any experience with C++ and including third party libraries for use from C++ code.

Comment: http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=pl&u=http://www.mblog.boo.pl/artykul-55-qt-fatal-error-no-such-file-or-directory-rozwiazanie.html&prev=/search%3Fq%3DQNetworkProxy:%2BNo%2Bsuch%2Bfile%2Bor%2Bdirectory%26client%3Dfirefox-a%26hs%3DFfB%26rls%3Dorg.mozilla:en-US:official%26channel%3Drcs

Comment: DLLs are _Dynamically_ Linked Libraries.

Comment: The order of arguments to `g++` matters a lot, and your `g++` command is probably wrong. The C++ source files should come first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DLLs can be used by dynamicly loading them and calling their used functions.

to call the exposed functions first define their syntax in the begining
suppose function is syntax is

```
BOOL MyFunction(int a,char* pszString)
```

then define syntax

```
#typedef BOOL (WINAPI *PMYFUNCTION)(int a,char* pszString)
```

then make object

```
PMYFUNCTION pfnMyFunction;
```

and get valid pointer by calling GetProcaddress after loadlibrarycall

```
HMODULE hlib= Loadlibrary("c:\\Mylib.dll");
if(hlib)

{    pfnMyFunction = (PMYFUNCTION)Getprocaddress(hlib,"MyFunction"); }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: i started to implement it this way (which was working so far) but then figured out where the headers I needed were.